# Is there any guide how to write bash scripts compatible with both CentOS and Ubuntu

Tags: bash, portability

I am simplifying my scenario here.

I've built a series of bash scripts and tested them under Ubuntu.

I want to make sure my scripts (bash syntax) work the same under CentOs.

Is there any guide how to write bash scripts compatible with both CentOS and Ubuntu ?

Or even better: is there any guide explains how create cross-linux-platform bash scripts?

**Update and Clarification**

In reference to @C.M. comment, I am not asking how bash works. I am asking if the bash interpreter code base is different among Linux distributions?

For example, Most of the Python 3's code base is the same among many many platform and behaves the same. To my experience Python code is very potable. The same apply to node.js code many other interpreters.

However, I am not sure if Bash benefits from the same portability. I might be wrong, but to me it seems that Bash is internally integrated inside Linux distributions. Am I correct? Do most linux distributions use the same source code repository to compile and distribute Bash?

Comment: The syntax will be mostly the same. There are only a few special bits that have changed in recent releases of the shell and they don't relate to _syntax as such_ (name reference variables and special formatting strings for dates, those are the things that spring to my mind). The main worries _I_ would have are not related to the `bash` shell syntax but to the external tools available (hopefully) on the different systems, and their semantics etc.  You have said nothing about what your script is doing, so it's difficult to say anything else.

Comment: Nope. You have to answer the "which of my tools and assumptions, working on Ubuntu, also work on CentOS" question for yourself. Overall, it's called "porting", but the easiest way is to try it and see.

Comment: By being aware of "portibility", one can write portable code. Ideally, this awareness starts with the project.

Comment: @waltinator, the tools outside bash syntax are out of the scope of this question. I am just worry about the bash syntax itself.

Comment: @waltinator, is it true that most Linux distributions compile the same "bash" source code, so the bash syntax will be identical?

Comment: Would you be able to explain why this question is being downvoted?

Comment: Have you tried to actually research before asking? I did a quick Google search for "bash guide" and found "About 59,900,000 results". (And I know personally that there are indeed guides for what you are asking, as I have used them myself.) This site, and most of it's users, will not be very helpful if you do not appear to have tried to help yourself first. If you _have_ tried, then edit your post and explain what you have tried and why it was not helpful to you.

Comment: @C.M., I am confused now. I've built so many bash Ubuntu bash scripts (some quite complex) and they are working very well for years.  How google search  "bash guide" would help me?

Comment: @C.M., I am not asking how bash works. I am asking if the bash interpreter code base is different among Linux distributions? Do you follow? For example, Most of the Python 3's code base is the same among many many platform and behaves the same. Is it the same with bash as an interpreter?

Comment: Bash is Bash, and CentOS and Ubuntu both being pretty much usual Linux distributions, the utilities you're going to have are the GNU utils (or if not, you'd know). What might matter more is the _age_ of the distribution version, e.g. if you take CentOS 7 from 2014 vs. Ubuntu 20.10, the older versions of some tools might not support some functions the newer ones do. For Bash, namerefs in Bash 4.3 are a big thing. (Not sure which Bash the older CentOSes have, though)

Comment: @ilkkachu, ok I see your point. On Ubuntu, my bash version is  "5.0.17(1)-release" and on CentOs my bash is "4.2.46(2)-release". So the version differences should be more concern than the actual platform difference.

Comment: @ilkkachu, Can i assume the same bash version between two platforms will be identical, and the script compatibility depends on the external program that the script calls?

Comment: @AllanXu: I understood what you were asking--You were asking are there any guides to help write _portable_ bash scripts, no a guide on how to write bash scripts in general. And my answer is, yes, there are such guides. I found some doing a search on Google, and as I said, I've used them in the past for myself. And some even go beyond bash: how to write portable scripts which work with other shells. For your updated question, "can you assume...": Yes, for the most part. Most distros may make small changes to the code, but not ones which will break bash portability with other bashes.

Comment: (continued) Most of the portability issues you will encounter are not with the shell itself, but with other issues: What software is installed by default in most base systems? Can you count on here always being a `/bin/bash`? What about the standard locations and/or paths? Does `/usr/share/lib' always exist? And so on. But there are guides out there for those issues as well, including Linux Standard Base and Hierarchical File System standards.

Comment: And for the final edit you made... No, bash is _not_ tightly integrated/coupled to any distro. bash is GPL. And it's only one of many shells which a distro might offer. A distro may make small changes, such as path locations, or bug fixes. Rarely will they change _how_ bash works--for the very reason you are asking! They do not want to make changes which break the billions of shell scripts out there.

Comment: @C.M., thanks for sharing your experience. You said "I found some doing a search on Google, and as I said, I've used them in the past for myself.". What Google search phrase did you use? Do you have any url to share? thanks !

Comment: @AllanXu: "bash guide", or if you want to narrow it down, "bash guide compatibility" or "portability". But even some of the introductory/basic bash guides cover a lot of things like portable scripts, although sometimes not in heavy detail. Again, try doing some research--this site is not here to be a research assistant. The reality is likely that you may even find things you did not think to ask that will help you even more.

Comment: @AllanXu there's this list of changes between Bash versions: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges Most of that is relatively minor, but namerefs can be a big thing if you want to make "library" functions. There's some minor differences in how Bash is compiled, e.g. Debian's/Ubuntu's `/etc/bash.bashrc` is different from the equivalent in CentOS. But it would be odd of either distro made big incompatible changes

Answer (score 2):

**The fundamental premise of the question has changed** (from "will a `bash` script written on one distrubition work on another") **, but the main thrust of the answer remains the same; the original answer is essentially preserved in this answer's conclusion.**

> I am asking if the bash interpreter code base is different among Linux distributions?

No, it is the same, notwithstanding some minor changes to how e. g. `.bashrc` is handled.  The `bash` source is GPL.  If a Linux distributor is distributing a modified version of `bash`, the modified source code should also be available for inspection and comparison to the general release.

> I want to make sure my scripts (bash syntax) work the same under CentOS

The *syntax of shell commands* in `bash` between distributions is identical given the same version of `bash`.

> For example, Most of the Python 3's code base is the same among many many platform and behaves the same.

This is a good analogy.  Much as the same Python code will work given the same (or similar) version of Python and installed libraries and utilities, so too will `bash`.

> I might be wrong, but to me it seems that Bash is internally integrated inside Linux distributions. Am I correct?

You are indeed wrong, as you imply that you suspect.  `bash` is no more "internally integrated" than other tools such as `ls` or `jq` or `rsync`, other than that `bash` is likely to be installed by default while e. g. `jq` may not.

> Is there any guide how to write bash scripts compatible with both CentOS and Ubuntu?

Ah, here is what appears to be the primary thrust of your many-pronged question.

There are probably many guides, but there is insufficient detail with respect to what sort of script(s) you are working on to give a really meaningful answer to this specific question.  `bash` itself though will not be a primary factor in how a script may work in one distribution but might not work in another.

`bash` scripts themselves will work perfectly fine on whichever distribution you move them to, so long as `bash` is installed.  For best compatibility, ensure the same (or a close) version of `bash` is installed on each host (for instance, you may see some minor compatibility issues depending on the script between `bash` v3 and `bash` v4 if a script avails itself of functionality introduced in the fourth release of `bash`).

However, *extrinsic* utilities may not be present or may work differently.

For instance, if you have a script *written for Ubuntu/Debian* that is designed to handle package management, it will be written to expect and use `.deb` package managers such as `apt`.  These tools are unlikely to be present and/or functional on a Red Hat-derived system, which uses `.rpm` package managers such as `yum`.  This is not a deficiency of `bash`, but rather a ramification of the environment in which it is run.